# Can we control webpage with respect to URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

I would like to show/hide divs in different url's. Div's show/hide based upon URL.

```
<div class="top">Top</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

If www.alldiv.com both the divs should be visible else if www.bottdiv.com "top div" should hide.

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Get URL: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/
Hide element: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: What's the backend for this? Is it a Java web app, php etc?

Comment: Are the pages the same?  Or do you have separate pages for the different urls?

Comment: Its bad practice to hide a DIV using javascript if you have no intention of showing it on that page. It will be better to hide it server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) you can do

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var host = location.hostname;
  $(".top").toggle(host.indexOf("alldiv")!=-1); // only show on alldiv
});
```

**Plain JS**

```
window.onload=function() {
  var host = location.hostname;
  var topDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
  topDiv.style.display=host.indexOf("alldiv")!=-1)?"block":"none";
}
```

that said, you really should not even send it to the client if you want to hide it unless you want to possibly show it later

Comment: In jQuery you forgot the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
  if(location.hostname == "www.alldiv.com") return;
  else if(location.hostname == "www.bottdiv.com") $(".top").hide();
})
```

That should do the trick as long as you import jQuery first.